# Can the ethnicity of medieval skulls be determined by shape?

Tags: race, archaeology

A recently published study, [*Race, Population Affinity, and Mortality Risk during the Second Plague Pandemic in Fourteenth-Century London, England*](https://journals.upress.ufl.edu/bioarchaeology/article/view/2403) states in the abstract:

> We investigate whether hazards of death from plague and physiological stress at a fourteenth-century plague cemetery (Royal Mint, London) differed between populations using N = 49 adults whose affiliation was established using macromorphoscopic traits. Compared to a nonplague cemetery (N = 96), there was a greater proportion of people of estimated African affiliation in the plague burials.
>
> [...]
> These findings may reflect premodern structural racism’s
> devastating effects.

The study appears to build on an earlier study by the same authors, [*“Officially absent but actually present”: Bioarchaeological evidence for population diversity in London during the Black Death, AD 1348–50*](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-815224-9.00005-1) which gives the basis for the idea that were significant numbers of black people in medieval London.

The previous study explains that DNA evidence is essentially not recoverable in most cases, so they rely on craniometry:

> The aDNA analysis [...] were only able to sequence the mtDNA from 5902. The
> haplotype of this female with Black African/Asian ancestry was U5b2a5,
> which is commonly found in England, Finland, and Tajikistan. Given their light stable isotope results, it is most likely that their maternal ancestry was from the British Isles. This result suggests that although these individuals are matching people with Black African/Asian ancestry in the macromorphoscopic database, in fact they may have had diverse heritage.

Earlier in the same study it is provided sample 5902 has **strong** macromorphoscopic Asian traits, while no craniometric traits could be assigned, while the DNA evidence suggests this is a person of British ancestry.

In the conclusion to that study they say

> Our study ... provides circumstantial evidence for the presence of
> males and females with Black African ancestry and dual heritage. These
> data are primary evidence for these people being “actually present” in
> Medieval London. However, the data provided a very unexpected result
> as it designated several individuals as having full or dual Asian
> ancestry. We propose that these results are a false positive, foremost
> because comparable temporally and geographically appropriate
> craniometric and macromorphoscopic reference data are not available.

They continue by saying that people's skulls have grown narrower since the medieval period. It seems that they are saying their algorithm, which assigns skulls to races based on separate craniometric and macromorphoscopic data, may at least in respect of macromorphoscopic data be rather unreliable, since it's comparing unknown skulls, which they say could be black or white, but they don't think can be Asian, with their dataset of skulls from the years 1965 and onwards. Despite acknowledging changes to skull features in the last six hundred years they are still happy to assign medieval London skulls as African or white, even while saying the algorithm is likely incorrectly determining them to be Asian.

This rather draws into question the subsequent study by the same author which is using "affiliation was established using macromorphoscopic traits" to determine that supposed black women were at outsized risk of plague, given the earlier study seems to give cause to doubt the reliability of such traits for 600-year-old skulls compared to more modern ones.

When the study was provided to [media](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2023/nov/21/women-with-black-african-ancestry-at-greater-risk-when-plague-hit-london) [outlets](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-67472933), the UK Equalities Minister, Kemi Badenoch, [condemned it](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2023/dec/13/badenoch-condemns-london-plague-study-after-mp-calls-it-woke-archaeology), describing it as "woke archaelogy".

Obviously regardless of whether the sample size is sufficient, if the study's methods are not accurately assigning race, the study's conclusions become worthless.

Can the ethnicity of medieval skulls be determined by shape?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable as currently framed. The key phrase in the first quote is "estimated African affiliation". An estimate by definition is not known with exact certainty. If you want a general review of how reliable such estimates might be, this looks promising: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6474543/. You may or may not also find more dissenting or supporting opinions about the particular paper you're asking about, but none of this really resolves the question.

Comment: @BrianZ that paper has the same co-author as the two above, although the first listed author for the two I quote is "Rebecca Redfern", who is absent in your link, as is all the rhetoric about "structural racism". There seems to be very substantial difference in tone aside as your link goes with measured "this is likely an African male" type statements, which aren't exciting, but when used to make sensational "medieval London was substantially African and they all died of plague because racism" clearly becomes so.

Comment: Why do you consider that the references provided in the paper - describing how this is done - are insufficient?

Comment: @JackAidley insufficient for what? As per the answer below it appears that the method or methods are of varying degrees of reliability for MODERN skulls, to the extent that I assume it would be reasonable if we were given 100 modern skulls at random from say white British, sub-Saharan African, or Japanese, it could classify them with a certain degree of confidence, however in this case the author has been accused of having an agenda to assert that medieval London was significantly non-white and that structural racism has obscured this reality, whereas in fact (?) it was almost entirely white

Comment: Personally, the line about "woke archaeology" doesn't add anything; tossing out the word "woke" just makes me dismiss the speaker, not believe they've properly analyzed the subject in question.

Comment: Insufficient to answer your question. The methods are described and referenced, so what is it about those methods do you think needs extra explanation? The claim of "an agenda" is completely irrelevant to the question re: medieval skulls.

Comment: @prosfilaes " tossing out the word "woke" just makes me dismiss the speaker"
That's not really the point here.
The speaker is black, and is the Equalities Minister, and is as such one of the one or two most important people in the UK in the area of equality/race relations, so her comments are notable. The fact that the study has caused sufficient disquiet to be discussed in Parliament establishes the notability of the skepticism about the claims. 'Properly analysing' the subject is the point of the question here.

Comment: It does help notability, though the media outlets would have been enough. But it's not really relevant to the question; to go to the article, "I agree with my honourable friend that this type of research is damaging to trust, to social cohesion and even to trust in health services." makes it clear the author isn't speaking about scientific issues with the research.

Comment: @JackAidley There are two separate questions: 1) how reliable are these methods for modern skulls, 2) is there any study which attempts to apply these technique for historic skulls, or discusses the validity of them when applied to historic skulls - i.e. if the method is reliable for modern skulls, does it follow that it should be reliable for historic skulls. If it does not follow then clearly the study is of no value, because it purports to show that historic black Londoners were more likely to die of the plague, when (it might be) that they were in fact white.

Answer (score 4):

> Can the ethnicity of medieval skulls be determined by shape?

What we can answer is that the ethnicity of modern skulls can be determined by shape, with a certain error rate.

There is a database of skull with associated ethnicity information, the Macromorphoscopic Databank (MaMD, see [Hefner, 2018](https://doi.org/10.1002/ajpa.23492)).  [In the study you mention](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-815224-9.00005-1) the particular method was validated on 1537 individuals from MaMD and the categorisation results were:

| Group | African | Asian | European |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| African | 153 | 83 | 69 |
| Asian | 45 | 544 | 90 |
| European | 22 | 85 | 446 |
| MIN86 | 5 | 13 | 23 |

> Classification matrix from a canonical analysis of the principal coordinates using macromorphoscopic data

Here the rows are the results recorded in the database (MIN86 is the medieval burial) and the columns are the results of the analysis.  As can be seen there are certainly errors, but the method categorises most individuals correctly.

Comment: Note that the book chapter cited is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Oddthinking I had somehow not noticed that.  I have edited the answer but it does make the whole question a little superfluous.

Comment: "there are certainly errors, but the method categorises most individuals correctly."

Your answer shows that a population comprised entirely of individuals of European heritage will be classified as 5% African, and 15% Asian.

In addition your final sentence "As can be seen there are certainly errors, but the method categorises most individuals correctly." doesn't really answer the question in that it's not clear why we should believe that medieval London was 44% non-European as per MIN86 in your table

Comment: A population of about 80% European and 20% Asian with zero Africans would produce these results quite well.

Comment: nor is it clear why the 'method categorises most individuals correctly' when the question is about the ability of this method to identify specifically medieval skulls, whereas in my question I note that the study author acknowledges skull shapes have changed in 600 years, so we would really need a source that addresses the validity of this method to identify the ethnicity of non-modern skulls.

Also the question's study addresses both 'Macromorphoscopic ' and 'craniometric' traits, whereas I think (?) you've only addressed Macromorphoscopic

Comment: @thelawnet, a goodness-of-fit test solidly rejects the hypothesis that medieval London's population consisted entirely of modern Europeans.